# Change look and feel of webparts and lists based on user level

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online

Has anyone ever modified the look and feel of their SharePoint site based on the user permission levels using CSS...

i.e. Admin web-part title is red but external users is black?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by using the [SecurityTrimmedControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.spsecuritytrimmedcontrol.aspx) in your masterpage or pagelayouts in the `<head>` tag.

Example:

```
<Sharepoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl runat=”server” Permissions=”ViewPages”>
<!-- CSS for external users -->
</SharePoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl>
<Sharepoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl runat=”server” Permissions=”FullMask”>
<!-- CSS for admin users -->
</SharePoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl>
```